# firebase functions config - delete data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I added some data to the encrypted config service of firebase using the syntax described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

Now that I don't need this anymore, I'd like to delete it from the config object. I understand that it's safely stored, I just don't want this config file to be polluted with information that I no longer need to use.

How do I delete data from the firebase functions config object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you linked to has a section on [additional environment commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#additional_environment_commands).

> `firebase functions:config:unset key1 key2` removes the specified keys from the config